# Defining the initial binding direction of a TwoWay binding?

Tags: reactiveui

I have a custom control (FilePicker) that I want to auto-fill with a value. The structure of my app looks something like this

```
ScreenView 
 -> FilePickerView
    -> FilePickerViewModel
 -> ScreenViewModel
    -> Loads Default Value
```

The problem is that the `ScreenViewModel` starts with some values pre-bound, but because the bindings in the `FilePickerView` are two-way, when I bind the `FilePickerView.SelectedPath` to the `ScreenViewModel` the value in `ScreenViewModel` is being overridden when the view activates.

Is there a way to either specify the default bind direction in `this.Bind(...)` or perhaps a way to say that default values should not be propagated?

Comment: I have a couple suggestions. But your question needs a little bit more detail regarding how your views/viewmodels are being setup and how the properties are being initialized and implemented in the viewmodel constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your implementation details, in your viewmodels you can use Skip()/SkipUntil()/etc... Rx extensions to defer initial values coming in from your views.